# NSUserDefaults in iOS 8 and under iOS 8

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I know NSUserDefaults saves data in a app, so data is cleared after deleting app under iOS 8. 
but data persists after deleting app in iOS 8.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Below codes works in iOS 8 (data is cleared after deleting app)

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.AppCompany.Appname"];
```

Does this code works under iOS 8?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your application in ios Simulator NSUserDefaults will not be cleared . it is the simulator bug .It work perfectly in ios device.